# Google-Apps-Script Project Trigger Error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to set a very simple trigger for a script.  Every time I try and save it, I get the following error message:

```
 We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.
```

There doesn't seem to be any reason why it wouldn't work.  It's simply trying to update every minute.  No other error messages are showing up.

Any thoughts/suggestions?  I've tried opening from multiple browsers, Google Drive, etc.  Nothing seems to change the error and I don't see any outage listed.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you installing a trigger manually through the code editor?  As opposed to running code.  Sometimes the code editor has periods where it has server error messages.  If it's a temporary problem, all you can do is wait.  If the error doesn't stop, you can report it on the issue tracker.  [Link to Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open)

Comment: I was simply clicking on the "trigger" icon to add it.  I eventually found that there was a bit of code that needed authorization, but the only way I got it to pop up was to run the debugger against the code.  Thanks for the reply!